# "Sign in with Intuit" button not showing after publishing application to server

Tags: vb.net, intuit-partner-platform

I built an app that using Intuit API V3 in VB.NET. I used some old code from a sample application that came from Intuit to input the login and connect buttons for IPP in the html. I think the underlying issue is in the html of my master page.

I get warnings on the line: - ipp:login href="OpenIdHandler.aspx" - "Unrecognized namespace 'ipp'."

I'm assuming I need a <%@ Register %> or <%@ Import %> to 'ipp' but I do not have any reference to the 'ipp' namespace anywhere in the master page html. Do I need one, if so, does anyone have an example? If not, what am I missing here?

Also, Internet Explorer is the only web browser that I have this problem. The button shows in all other browsers except Internet Explorer when run off the server. I am hosting the application in IIS 8 on Windows Server 2012. When I run the application in my development environment the button shows in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have used intuit script then you should be good to go -
"https://js.appcenter.intuit.com/Content/IA/intuit.ipp.anywhere.js"

If you check the sample app provided by intuit, it also gets the warnings same as you do.
We support IE9 and above for our widgets but there have been some issues with widgets on IE and our engineering team is working on it.

Please verify your settings against the sample app from Intuit and see if it works.
https://github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/